# Priority of carbons attached to chiral group, one with double bonded oxygen, one with two oxygens

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

I have a chiral carbon. Two of the atoms attached to the carbon are other carbon atoms. One of those carbons has a double bonded oxygen and a methyl group attached. The other has two oxygens and a methyl group. Which carbon substituent has higher priority?

Comment: Could you edit the question to give an example of such a molecule, and try to apply the priority rules to it? The answer might depend on the context.

Comment: The double bonded oxygen counts as two atoms attached. The first is the real oxygen atom with no substituents. The second is a phantom oxygen that is like any other oxygen except it has immediately lower priority than a real oxygen atom.

Answer (score 1):

Given the same atom, those bond via triple bonds have higher precedence over double and double bonds have higher precedence over single. This is exemplified [here](http://www.chemeddl.org/resources/stereochem/priorities11.htm) and, a bit more formal covering all CIP-rules, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn-Ingold-Prelog_priority_rules).

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE.  I edited the answer a bit, because even if the original question leaves space for a little variation (second edit), the original OP eventually seeks an binary answer of 'either stop, or go'.